# How to set the environment for working with poor eyesight?

Tags: linux, windows, accessibility

I program in various web languages. I have poor eyesight, small field of view, myopia, astigmatism, photophobia, etc. I need to create the perfect environment for working and using a computer. My main requirement is dark mode, high contrast, high brightness, large scaling with a small area to observe.

Until now, I used a laptop with Win10 on an external monitor, but due to its size, I have to "look around" on it. I have a 15-inch laptop (HP Omen), a smartphone (Note9), a 22-inch monitor and an old, good IBM / Lenovo T60 (which of course has a very dark screen). I tried to use TeamViewer on the phone (Note9) + keyboard and mouse, but a large lag and not supporting keyboard shortcuts and mouse completely rejects this solution. I also tried using the Linux distribution in VirtualBox, which was open in a small window, but either it was too cumbersome (scrolling websites sideways, the application windows would not fit), or the font size was much too small. In addition, I don't often use linux so I don't know if it is possible to adapt it completely to dark colors. Another option I tested was using spacedesk with a telephone. Unfortunately, even more lag than in TeamViewer and various graphic artifacts.

Any hint of configuration, software or settings will be helpful! Do you have any suggestions? Thank you in advance for all the answers!

Comment: Can't really help you very much, but well, read [_Low vision and how I see the web_](https://paul.bone.id.au/2017/11/26/how-i-see-the-web/) if you have not, maybe there's any useful idea there.

Comment: Thank you for this link @uprego . I have read a part so far and admit that a lot can be learned from it.

Comment: Anyone have any other suggestions?